# I'm trying to install the JACO package to access by the ROS. But i can't use right the command rosmake. Can anyone help, please?

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

root@mecateam-desktop:~/fuerte_workspace/ros-jaco-arm# rosmake ros-jaco-arm
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['ros-jaco-arm']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /root/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140717-185617
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['ros-jaco-arm'] to:
[]
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['ros-jaco-arm']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186973/i%27m-trying-to-install-the-jaco-package-to-access-by-the-ros.-but-i-can%27t-use-right-the-command-rosmake.-can-anyone-help,-please?/) by [Priscila Martins](https://answers.ros.org/users/19770/priscila-martins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-07-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-07-18**:
Please post the link to the repository of this package. I can't find it on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The folder doesn't contain a stack.xml so it is not recognized as a ROS meta-package (stack).

So you will have to rosmake individual packages inside that folder.

Please note that rosmake will soon be obsolete. This means a catkin package is much better than a rosmake package.

I would suggest that you use @fivef 's JacoROS. It is very stable. I just tried it and seems to work very fine! There is also a fork that I have created with certain added features.

Please see:

https://github.com/ksatyaki/JacoROS

https://github.com/fivef/JacoROS

Have a nice day.
Chittaranjan

---

Originally posted by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) with karma: 1247 on 2014-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Priscila Martins](https://answers.ros.org/users/19770/priscila-martins/) on 2014-07-24**:
Good night Chittaranjan, thanks for  your help. But now when i try to execute the comand: roslaunch jaco start.launch
Occur this error: ERROR: cannot launch node of type [jaco/jaco]: can't locate node [jaco] in package [jaco]
you can you give a clue to fix this error?

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-25**:
Please tell me what all you have done. Enumerate the steps taken.